# Swagger UI not working as expected while service behind Nginx reverse-proxy

Tags: nginx, swagger

I use swagger-ui-express package(`https://github.com/scottie1984/swagger-ui-express`) (Node.js) and work fine with this config:

```
const swaggerUi = require('swagger-ui-express');
const swaggerDocument = require('./swagger.json');
app.use('/api-docs',swaggerUi.serve, swaggerUi.setup(swaggerDocument));
```

when directly got to /api-docs every thing is fine,
but when i come from nginx for example `host/myApp/api-docs` redirect me to `host/api-docs` and it's obvious that after redirect I get 404

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem was for the `swagger-ui-express` middleware that redirect user to host/api-docs and don't use the prefix of path, so I solved this problem with a trick I use middleware with this path :

```
const swaggerUi = require('swagger-ui-express');
const swaggerDocument = require('./swagger.json');
app.use('/app-prefix/api-docs',swaggerUi.serve, swaggerUi.setup(swaggerDocument));
```

and in nginx I defined two location :

```
  location /app-prefix/api-docs {
      proxy_pass http://172.18.0.89:3000/app-prefix/api-docs;
  }

  location /app-prefix/ {
      proxy_pass http://172.18.0.89:3000/;
  }
```

so when user request to nginx , nginx route it to application second path :
`/app-prefix/api-docs`

and after that swagger middlware redirect it to `host/app-prefix/api-docs`
and redirect to correct path,
now application route and swagger works fine.

Answer (score 2):

add this options and test it :

````
    explorer: true,
    swaggerOptions: {
        validatorUrl: null
    }
};
app.use('/api-docs',swaggerUi.serve, swaggerUi.setup(swaggerDocument, swaggerOption));```
````

Comment: Thanks fateme,  but I tested your solution , and still not working.

Answer (score 2):

This is an old question, but I just run into the same problem.  I am able to resolve this without using ngnix rewrite.

```
// serve the swagger ui in a temporary directory
app.use('/temp-api-docs', swaggerUi.serve, swaggerUi.setup(swaggerDocument));

// swagger-ui-express middleware that redirect user to /api-docs will not be aware the prefix of path by ngnix
const apiDocsRedirectPath = "application/prefix/go/here".concat('/temp-api-docs/');
app.get('/api-docs', function(req, res) {
    res.redirect(apiDocsRedirectPath);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I also had this problem and the marked correct answer worked for me. However, I do not understand how it is working because I don't know much about Nginx.

Here is my solution for future people with this issue.

```
this.app.use(
    "/api-docs",
    swaggerUi.serve,
    swaggerUi.setup(openapiSpecification as OpenAPIV3.Document)
);
```

The express app itself is behind an nginx proxy which looks like this

```
location /api/v1/myapp/ {
    proxy_pass http://myapp:3001/;
}
```

So when a request is made to `example.com/api/v1/myapp/api-docs` it comes out of the proxy to myapp like `myapp:3001/api-docs` which is fine, up until (I think) swagger UI express tries to load resources from `example.com/api-docs` which will 404 of course.

I solved it by adding this as a redirect.

```
location /api/v1/myapp/ {
    proxy_pass http://myapp:3001/;
}

location /api-docs/ {
    return 302 /api/v1/myapp/api-docs/;
}
```

So now when swagger goes off to request things at `example.com/api-docs` it is redirected to the correct location block and works like normal.

Again, not an expert with this but this seems to work and I think its easy to understand.

The caveat is that you are stuck with just one /api-docs so if you have multiple swagger endpoints this does not work.

Answer (score 0):

None of the answers worked for me. I've solved it using a custom middleware.

middlewares/forwardedPrefixSwagger.js

```
const forwardedPrefixSwagger = async (req, res, next) => {
  req.originalUrl = (req.headers['x-forwarded-prefix'] || '') + req.url;
  next();
};
```

app.js

```
app.use('/docs/node/api/swagger/', middlewares.forwardedPrefixSwagger, swaggerUi.serve, swaggerUi.setup(swaggerFile, options));
```

Note: For this to work the URL must include a trailing slash.